# Compose multiple stream

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need your help understanding how to compose multiple `Stream` objects in C#.

## Scenario

I have a stream as an input, and I want to read this stream, compress it, encrypt it, and then write it to another stream.

## Question

What's the best way to accomplish this without using temp files?

## Edit

@itsme86: Using a byte array is not a good idea for my purpose as the file could be significant and generate memory problems.

@Xerillio: Naturally, I already tried to use a temp file, but it's not a good solution: longer processing times and a large amount of disk space.

@Stewart Ritchie: I don't want memory problems, so I'd like to compose the streams and write the result directly on the final "support."

Thank you,

Attilio

Comment: Can't you just store the intermediary data in a `byte[]` array or similar? Are you concerned about large files?

Comment: The "best" way is a very subjective question. Have you tried something first? How is that working or how is it not working?

Comment: Are you aiming to do it all in-memory and avoid file-system IO overhead?

Comment: Have you considered using the decorator pattern and using MemoryStream as intermediary objects?

Comment: @Josh can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @AttilioGelosa it's nice to see you've identified some issues you are trying to overcome - that helps clarify the question. Could you show us how you have tried overcoming these issues? Have you tried streaming the data through compression and encryption? What's blocking you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compress a stream, use something like GZipStream.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream?view=netcore-3.1

```
using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + ".gz"))
using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
}
```

Comment: My problem is not only to compress a stream... that's the easy part of the problem... ;-) Please, see my edit question for more details.